# SQL: Locating differences based on a column in a table

Tags: sql

I have at table which has a discount applied across currencies, I want to highlight the rows which have a different percentage

E.g:

```
category | Item | Currency| Discount
Food.      Apple.  USD       20%
Food.      Apple.  GBP       20%
Food.      Apple.  EUR       10%
Drink.     Coke.   USD       20%
Drink.     Coke.   GBP       20%
Drink.     Coke.   EUR       20%
Drink.     Coke.   AUD       5%
```

So in this instance I want to return
Drink.     Coke.   AUD       5%
and     Food.      Apple.  EUR       10%

Im getting my source data into a CTE and I have tried a partition over to numbers to highlight the differences with no luck. Any advice?

Comment: Please share with us: your code (best try you think you have). Also please explain little bit more what you need because "rows which have a different percentage" is not clear. Different than what ? What if there was a Drink, Coke, AUD, 6% ?

Comment: What if `Food,Orange,USD,10%` and `Food,Orange,AUD,5%`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by discount) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row with the smallest discount for each category.  If you want multiple rows when there is a tie, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT category, Item, Currency, Discount
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.category = t1.category AND
                    t2.Item = t1.Item AND
                    t2.Discount > t1.Discount);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Read in plain English, the above query returns any record for which we can find at least one other record of the same category and item (and any currency), but having a larger discount.